# glob module only iterates over one file in directory

Tags: python, file, loops, directory, glob

I am trying to cycle through a series of files in a directory with `glob.glob(*.txt)` and take only one line from each file. I have managed to get it to cycle through one file and get the correct line, however, the iterations stop after one file, rather than continuing through all files in the directory. I am sure this is a minor detail I'm overlooking, but I cant figure out what it is. The full code is:

```
import glob
def compile():
    for filename in glob.glob('*.txt'):
        outfile = 'Stats_Table.txt'
        with open(filename, 'r') as file, open(outfile, 'w') as out:
            print('comparison       F_calc       F_table       t_calc        t_table           p', file = out)
            print('_______________________________________________________________________________', file = out)
            for i, line in enumerate(file):
                if i == 2:
                    print(filename[:-4],'    ', line, file = out)
compile()
```

The files that I am taking data from are in the form:

```
F_calc       F_table       t_calc        t_table           p
______________________________________________________________
29.63872       9.27663       10.27471       2.25956       0.00147
```

and the final result that I am getting after only one iteration is:

```
comparison       F_calc       F_table       t_calc        t_table           p
______________________________________________________________________________
swa-teccu1      58.74018       9.27663       32.2219       2.30274       5e-05
```

EDIT: The working file, for anyone interested is the following:

```
import glob
def compile():
    outfile = 'Stats_Table.txt'
    with open(outfile, 'w') as out:
        print('comparison       F_calc       F_table       t_calc        t_table           p', file = out)
        print('_______________________________________________________________________________', file = out)
        for filename in glob.glob('*.txt'):
            with open(filename, 'r') as file:
                for i, line in enumerate(file):
                    if i == 2:
                        print(filename[:-4],'    ', line.strip(), file = out)
compile()
```

Comment: You are reopening the output file on every iteration. It will be overwritten like this. Try mode `'a'` instead or open the file outside of the loop.

Comment: @KlausD That worked. Thank you!  I will post the working script in the question as an edit.